# Implementing a Indoor Map

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, 3d, navigation

**I am trying to create a map like this here:**

[image]

1. How can i that be achieved?
2. How to show it on android?
3. How would i add a course/path to it? how to show that on android ?

All I know that it is just an Image, How is it possible to pin-point a place on an Image on Android :

[image]

**[Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobilefringe.squareone&hl=en) is a link to the app that has these features.**

Comment: Hi,Mo Adel ,can you please help me in knowing how you solved this??? especially showing a path on image and making image interactive...any help will be really appreciated...
 thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**How can i that be achieved?**

You need  3D models such as OBJ, FBX, STL files etc. You also need some texture images. And all theses are usually referred to as **ASSETS**.

**How to show it on android?**

You need some 3D graphics framework or implement your own [OpenGL renderers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html). Some well known 3D toolkits include:

- [LigGdX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/): a very good java 3D toolkits
- [OSG for Android](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//wiki/Support/PlatformSpecifics/Android): very heavy but powerful framework, using C++/JNI and NDK
- Use [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) to program use low level OpenGL APIs
- [jPCT 3D engine](http://www.jpct.net/index.php): the free 3D solution for Java and Android
- [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/): Recommended! But this is usually coded in C# or Javascript, and you may take some time to adapt to it.
- [Mono For Android](http://monodevelop.com/Download/Mono_For_Android): cross platform, again you might learn quite sth.

**How would i add a course/path to it? how to show that on android?**

You need to implement that on your own. You might place a few anchor points and connect them in network/graphs.